# Lumen api issue

Tags: php, laravel, api, lumen

I've installed Lumen framework, it works but I can't get access to the api.
When I just go to the public folder `https://example.com/lumen/public/` it shows response correctly: **Lumen (5.5.2) (Laravel Components 5.5.*)**

Then I've made simple api by this [tutorial](https://auth0.com/blog/developing-restful-apis-with-lumen/) but can not access to this api `https://example.com/lumen/public/api/authors`

As a result I have `HTTP ERROR 500`

Then I've made exactly the same project on my Cloud9 hosting for testing and there I can access to the api page without an issue.

I don't understand why there is an error for Lumen's api request on one of my hostings in fact that projects are the same? What it can be? Is there any special configs for Lumen routing/api e.t.c.?

Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: with it being a server error id ask you to check spellings and possible typos as it shows as installed correctly. (I don't mean to sound patronising but its the little things that bite you in the ass)

Comment: Check for servers php and mysql version.

Comment: The first thing you always do on a 500 _Internal Server Error_, is you go check the relevant log files _on_ the server.

Comment: As for Laravel, `public` should not be called in the URL, but is the `DocumentRoot` of your server. https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.7#installing-lumen What server are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write .htaccess file on root as below :

```
 ## enable rewrites

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^lumen(.*)/$ /lumen/public/index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

then you can call as below :

http://example.com/lumen/public/api/authors

You can also refer below link for more details.

https://auth0.com/blog/developing-restful-apis-with-lumen/

Comment: Thanks! Now it's working. One more question...Is it possible to make Lumen work for Nginx out of the box (as for Apache) without additional nginx.conf editing?